# Finding convex optimization books for beginners.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, book-recommendation

Currently, I am a year three undergraduate studying EECS. Having a great interest in optimization theories, I suppose I should start with learning convex optimization. However, my school only offers convex optimization courses for graduate students, and I cannot find an appropriate book to learn it myself.

I have taken the following maths courses:

1. Calculus I & II (B+ and A-)
2. Linear Algebra (A+)
3. Probability (A)
4. Introduction to convex analysis (A-)
5. Discrete Mathematics (A+)
6. Numerical Analysis (A)
7. Mathematical-Physical methodology (B)

Some of my senior classmates suggested that the classic by Steven Boyd is a good option, but I find reading such a massive book for a newbie quite cumbersome and inappropriate. Are there any other recommendations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Boyd & Vandenberghe book sometimes goes into unwanted details (e.g. I am currenly reading chapter 11 on Interior point methods, there are too many numerical results). And on other occasions it is too short in its explanations. Still, the book is fairly clear and readable, it is not obvious to find a better one.

Comment: Possibly "Interior Point Algorithms: Theory and Analysis" by Yinyu Ye? Possibly a bit of a deep dive, but solid. Not really a convex book, but has a lot of very relevant stuff.

Comment: If you have convex analysis and linear algebra you might be ok with the graduate level courses?

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed, but the course has collided with my schedule, and I cannot go to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this classic book by Bubeck: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4980

Answer (score 0):

This book is written specifically with undergraduates in mind https://doi.org/10.1142/8527